# Symmetry Operation Matrices of $I_h$ Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry

I wanted to find the symmetry operation matrix for $I_h$ point group. My background is in chemistry and did not find operation matrices to Ih group online -- people seem to focus on the 32 types of crystal point groups instead of $I_h$ point group.
A related question seems to be discussed here: [How to generate the icosahedral groups $I$ and $I_h$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356359/how-to-generate-the-icosahedral-groups-i-and-i-h)
I'm confused about the process of generating the 120 matrices based on the four matrices discussed on this link.
Any information would be highly appreciated.

Comment: All $60$ matrices of group $I$ are listed [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B). This is the Russian-language wikipedia page. Interestingly, the English-language one does not have this enumeration. To get all matrices of group $I_h$ from $I$, one has to add their opposite matrices to $I$ matrices.

Comment: This is great information -- but is there any interface to any programming language?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the matrix representations available from wolfram mathematica via `FiniteGroupData["Icosahedral", "MatrixRepresentation"]`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).